# Class does not name a type error even when class header file included in C++?

Tags: c++, class

This occurs for my first member function for the class 'complex_test' (the constructor) so I assume I'm getting the same error for the rest of the functions.
FULL ERROR:error: 'complex_test' does not name a type.
 The class implementation file below:

```html
#include <fstream>           // For ifstream, ofstream classes
#include "Complex.hpp"       // For complex class declaration
#include "ComplexTest.hpp"   // For complex_test class declaration

complex_test::complex_test()
{
}

void complex_test::run()
{
    std::ifstream fin("complex-in.txt");

    std::ofstream fout("complex-out.txt");

    int n; fin >> n;

    for (int testcase = 0; testcase < n; ++testcase) {
        run_test(fin, fout);
    }

    // Close the input and output files.
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}

void complex_test::run_test(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout)
{
    // Read the four double values.
    double real1, imag1, real2, imag2;
    fin >> real1 >> imag1 >> real2 >> imag2;

    complex c1(real1, imag1);

    complex c2(real2, imag2);

    complex sum      = c1.add(c2);
    complex diff     = c1.sub(c2);
    complex product  = c1.mul(c2);
    complex quotient = c1.div(c2);

    fout << "c1 = " << c1.to_string() << ", c2 = " << c2.to_string() << std::endl;
    fout << "c1 + c2 = " << sum.to_string() << std::endl;
    fout << "c1 - c2 = " << diff.to_string() << std::endl;
    fout << "c1 * c2 = " << product.to_string() << std::endl;
    fout << "c1 / c2 = " << quotient.to_string() << std::endl;
    }
```

The class header for complex_test class:

```html
#ifndef COMPLEX_HPP 
#define COMPLEX_HPP

#include <fstream>     

using namespace std;

class complex_test {
public:
    complex_test();
    void run();
private:
    void run_test(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout);
};

#endif
```

In addition to this I get an error in the function implementation for the class 'complex' in line 62 for the get_real(), the compiler says it is not in scope, yet I defined it in the very same file?

Exact wording of error: 'get_real' was not declared in this scope.

```html
#include <iomanip>      // For fixed, setprecision()
#include <sstream>      // For stringstream class
#include "Complex.hpp"  // For the complex class declaration
#include <cmath>


    complex::complex()
    {
        init(0,0);
    }

 complex::complex(double init_real, double init_imag)
 {
    init(init_real, init_imag);
 }

 double complex::get_imag()
 {
     return m_imag;
 }

    double complex::get_real()
    {
        return m_real;
    }

void complex::init(double init_real, double init_imag)
    {
        m_real = init_real;
        m_imag = init_imag;
    }

void complex::set_imag(double s)
    {
        m_imag = s;
    }

void complex::set_real(double s)
    {
        m_real = s;
    }

std::string complex::to_string()
{
    std::stringstream sout;
    sout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4);
    sout << "(" << get_real();
    double imag = get_imag();
    if (imag < 0) {
        sout << " - " << -imag << 'i';
    } else if (imag > 0) {
        sout << " + " << imag << 'i';
    }
    sout << ")";
    return sout.str();
}



complex complex::add(complex& rhs_op)
{
    double sum_real = get_real() + rhs_op.get_real();
    double sum_imag = get_imag() + rhs_op.get_imag();
    complex sum(sum_real, sum_imag);
    return sum;
}


complex complex::div(complex& rhs_op)
{
    complex inverse = rhs_op.invert();
    complex quotient = mul(inverse);
    return quotient;
}

complex invert()
{
    double denom = std::pow(get_real(), 2) + std::pow(get_imag(), 2);
    double inv_real = get_real() / denom;
    double inv_imag = get_imag() / denom;
    complex inverse(inv_real, inv_imag);
    return inverse;
}


complex complex::mul(complex& rhs_op)
{
    double prob_real = get_real() * rhs_op.get_real() - (get_imag() * rhs_op.get_imag());
    double prod_imag = get_imag() * rhs_op.get_real() + (get_real * rhs_op.get_imag());
    complex product(prod_real, prod_imag);
    return product;
}


complex complex::negate()
{
    complex neg(-get_real, -get_imag);
    return neg;

}


complex complex::sub(complex& rhs_op)
{
    complex negation = rhs_op.negate();
    complex diff = add(negation);
    return diff;
}
```

The header file for class 'complex':

```html
#ifndef COMPLEX_HPP  
#define COMPLEX_HPP

#include <string> 

class complex

{
    public:

    complex();

    complex(double,double);

    complex add(complex&);

    complex div(complex&);

    complex invert();

    complex mul(complex&);

    complex negate();

    complex sub(complex&);

    double get_imag();

    double get_real();

    void set_imag(double);

    void set_real(double);

    std::string to_string();

    private:

    void init(double , double );

    double m_real;

    double m_imag;
};


#endif
```

Comment: Post the full error messages.  Don't paraphrase them.

Comment: Your invert, mul, negate, and sub are declared as functions, not member functions.

Comment: @jamesdlin just added it for both errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two lines of both of the shown header files appear to be:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_HPP 
#define COMPLEX_HPP
```

Which means that including either header file will make subsequent inclusion of the other header file a big fat nothing.

P.S. You will also remove more possibilities of other mysterious compilation errors by [immediately forgetting that "using namespace std;" is a part of the C++ language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Do yourself a favor and completely get rid of it, especially in header files. It will take a little bit of time getting used it to it, but explicitly referencing the `std` namespace every time it's needed will quickly become second nature, and mostly an automatic, subconscious process, very quickly.